# iOS 5 hiding tabBarItem text labels

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Is it possible to hide the text labels in a `tabBarItem`?

My text labels are part of the images I'm using as a replacement because they have some bevels/drop shadows that I can't replicate in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, in the viewcontroller associated to the tab, you can set:

```
self.title=@"";
```

But in case of `UINavigationController` this also  sets to `@""` the title of the navigationbar, so you've to redefine the `titleView` of the the navigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

You may just leave text field blank. 
For example:

```
-(void)setBlankTitleForTabBarItem:(UITabBarItem*)Item{
    [Item setTitle:nil];
}
```

Comment: This works well, but looks like there space for the text is still there and therefore the images are smaller...